# Selenium JavaScript: Anonymous vs named functions

Tags: javascript, selenium

For Selenium JavaScript, it seems that every example I read on the interwebs explains that the best way to deal with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript is to create an anonymous function with `.then()` to find/interact with each element on the page, as opposed to creating named functions and calling them at runtime.

For example, if I wanted to login to a site with credentials:

Context:

```
'use strict';
const WebDriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const By    = WebDriver.By;
const until = WebDriver.until;
var driver = new WebDriver.Builder().withCapabilities(
    WebDriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
```

Example A:

```
driver.get("http://somefakewebsite.com")
.then(function(){ driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("myLogin"); })
.then(function(){ driver.findElement(By.id("password").sendKeys("myPassword"); })
.then(function(){ driver.findElement(By.id("submit").click(); })
.then(function(){ driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("pageId")), 5000); })
.then(function(){ driver.findElement(By.id("buttonOnlyAvailableAfterLogin").click(); })
```

Example B:

```
function inputLogin(driver){
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("myLogin");
}

function inputPassword(driver){
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("myPassword");
}

function clickSubmit(driver){
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
}

function waitAfterLogin(driver){
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("pageId")), 5000);
}

function clickSomeButtonAfterLogin(driver){
    driver.findElement(By.id("buttonOnlyAvailableAfterLogin")).click();
}

driver.get("http://somefakewebsite.com")
.then(inputLogin(driver))
.then(inputPassword(driver))
.then(clickSubmit(driver))
.then(waitAfterLogin(driver))
.then(clickSomeButtonAfterLogin(driver))
```

My question: **Is there an advantage to using Example A over Example B?** It seems they both work when trying to run. Although the second way seems like more lines of code, it just feels more organized and easier to read (because the named functions are telling me exactly what is going on, rather than trying to read the logic in the anonymous functions in Example A).

Comment: Example B executes all of your methods (`inputLogin`, `inputPassword`, `clickSubmit`) immediately, and passes `undefined` to the `then`s, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're saying is correct.. My Example B script runs fine and is able to interact with elements available only after the login.. I have edited my example to reflect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the 2 is the following:

**Example A** waits for the promise to fulfill, then chains each method after one another.

**Example B** is roughly equivalent with the following:

```
const result = driver.get("http://somefakewebsite.com")

inputLogin(driver)
inputPassword(driver)
clickSubmit(driver)
waitAfterLogin(driver)
clickSomeButtonAfterLogin(driver)

result
  .then(undefined)
  .then(undefined)
  .then(undefined)
  .then(undefined)
  .then(undefined)
```

If **Example B** works for you, then probably `driver.get` doesn't need to be fulfilled in order for the methods on it to work, or the question is missing crucial parts of your code. Or the Promise fulfills immediately. Or it blocks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have left out that crucial piece you are referring to. I have added "content" at the top of my examples to elaborate.